# Make string into arraylist with individual characters Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, split

I have a `String` called `new_alpha` which contains only characters (no whitespace). How do I split it so that each character is a different element in a new `ArrayList`?

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new_alpha.split("")))`

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for this. I'll try it!

Comment: @shmosel How do I assign a variable name to this ArrayList?

Comment: @PalpableCoral ` just assign it to `ArrayList<String>` object.

Comment: `new_alpha.codePoints().mapToObj(cp -> new String(new int[] { cp }, 0, 1)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(new_alpha.toCharArray())`

Answer (score 0):

```
int len=new_alpha.length();
ArrayList<Character> arr=new ArrayList<Character>();
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{ arr.add(new_alpha.charAt(i));
}
```

Your all character of String convert into ArrayList;